# Incompatible operator return when checking animation data

Tags: python, add-on, error

I have the code:

```
import bpy
import math

scn = bpy.context.scene

class AutoReverse(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.move_operator"
    bl_label = "Auto Reverse"

    def execute(self, context):
        # get keyframes of object list
        def get_keyframes(obj_list):
            keyframes = []
            for obj in obj_list:
                anim = obj.animation_data
                if anim is not None and anim.action is not None:
                    for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
                        for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
                            x, y = keyframe.co
                            if x not in keyframes:
                                keyframes.append((math.ceil(x)))
            return keyframes

        # get all selected objects
        selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

        # check if it has animation data
        if bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action is not None:

            # get all frames with assigned keyframes
            keys = get_keyframes(selection)

            # print all keyframes
            print (keys)   

            # print first and last keyframe
            firstFrame = keys[0]
            lastFrame = keys[-1]

            # checking if it is baked
            if len(keys) < lastFrame:
                #baking the animation
                bpy.ops.nla.bake(frame_start=firstFrame, frame_end=lastFrame, step=1, bake_types={'OBJECT'})


            #scale it by -1 to reverse it
            old_type = bpy.context.area.type
            bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
            bpy.ops.graph.interpolation_type(type='CONSTANT')
            bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 1
            bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(-1, 1, 1))
            bpy.context.area.type = old_type
            return {'FINISHED'}

        else:
             self.report({'ERROR'}, 'There is no animation')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AutoReverse)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I get the error

RuntimeError: class OBJECT_OT_add, function execute: incompatible return value , str(, Function.result expected a set, not a NoneType)

From testing I think it's from this line:

```
if bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action is not None:
```

(BTW I know there is an almost identical question, but he fixes it himself and I can't find a similar error in mine)

I would like to know why it occurs (beyond just purely what the error tells me), how to fix it, or whether there is a suitable replacement to the line above to avoid the error alltogether, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I forgot that if you use  `self.report({'ERROR'}, 'There is no animation')`, you must add `return {'CANCELLED'}`.